# Using white space in key value for hashing in perl

Tags: perl, hash, whitespace

Can we safely use hash tables where the key value would include white spaces in between. For ex:

```
my $key1="Dave 2314";
my $key2="John 3212";

$newhash{$key1}= 35;
$newhash{$key2}= 46;
```

I used similar piece of code in one of my program. I feel like the hashing do work, but exists function don't go well=>

```
print "Found\n" if (exists $newhash{$searchKey})
```

This gives absurd results. Sometimes it works well and return correct response if the key is present and sometimes it doesn't for the very same input. Is having white spaces in the keys the reason for such absurd functioning?

Comment: No, the very same code is used for hashing the key in both operators, and any character can be used in hash keys. You probably have a trailing line feed in one place but not the other.

Comment: Can you please show us a stand-alone program that reproduces the problem? Most likely @ikegami is correct in that your `$searchKey` contains newlines or other whitespace, while `$key1` and `$key2` don't. Maybe use https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper and inspect the data you have.

Comment: If you use Data::Dumper, you'll get best results by doing `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` first

Comment: Your repetitive use of *absurd* may be absurd

Answer (score 1):

What absurd results do you get? The hash doesn't care what you have in the keys. Are you sure that you have the right thing in `$searchKey`? If you are taking that from user input, is there an extra newline on the end?

This works as it should:

```
my %newhash;

my $key1="Dave 2314";
my $key2="John 3212";

$newhash{$key1} = 35;
$newhash{$key2} = 46;

print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{$key1};
```

But, there's another issue. You can have code in the braces for the hash element single access. When you have just a scalar variable it works. This is a syntax error because there's a bare word `Dave`, a space, and a literal number `1234`:

```
print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{Dave 2314};
```

This is not a syntax error though, because there's a function named `Dave` (that just happens to return a key that exists). I'm confident this isn't your problem:

```
sub Dave { 'John 3212' }
print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{Dave 2314};
```

Written another way:

```
sub Dave { 'John 3212' }
print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{ Dave(2314) };
```

And yet another way:

```
print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{ join ' ', qw(John 3212 ) };
```

You should have quoted that key if it was literal:

```
print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{'Dave 2314'};
```

You can have unquoted strings if they don't look like code. This looks like `'Dave'`:

```
print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{Dave};
```

But what about this? That dot is actually the string concatenation operator and it thinks `Dave` is a bare word. It you haven't defined a subroutine, this is a syntax error:

```
print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{Dave.John};
```

This works though. The thing before the dot is a subroutine call but the thing after is a string:

```
sub Dave { 'John 3212' }
print "Found\n" if exists $newhash{Dave.John};
```

So there are some weird edge cases. But I typically don't have this problem because I always quote literal keys.

Comment: It seems like majority of this post explains a condition that the OP has not described: using a non-scalar as a key.  It's not incorrect, but was a lot to read when it may not apply to the experienced problem.

Comment: I answer questions for future searchers. These are the problems I commonly see when the person isn't using the hash key they expect.  The first paragraph probably solves this person's problem though.

Comment: Understood, might I propose a horizontal rule to separate these concerns?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for investing your time. 
The issue was in my code itself. The entire logic was based on a flag variable which i didnt reset properly as and when required. 
So to answer my own question, whitespaces in between the key string should not be a problem.